# Flexbox columns in ascending order

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-multicolumn-layout

I'm working with some items in a list:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2</li>
  <li>Item3</li>
  <li>Item4</li>
  <li>Item5</li>
  <li>Item6</li>
  <li>Item7</li>
  <li>Item8</li>
</ul>
```

and I'm trying to get them to break into two columns using flexbox, which gives the result of this:

```
+--------------------+
|                    |
| Item1       Item2  |
|                    |
| Item3       Item4  |
|                    |
| Item5       Item6  |
|                    |
| Item7       Item8  |
|                    |
+--------------------+
```

But I'm trying to sort them in ascending order so it appears like this:

```
+--------------------+
|                    |
| Item1       Item5  |
|                    |
| Item2       Item6  |
|                    |
| Item3       Item7  |
|                    |
| Item4       Item8  |
|                    |
+--------------------+
```

Not sure how to achieve that by using CSS + Flexbox unless I need to add some JS into the mix?

Here's a demo on Codepen:

https://codepen.io/ultraloveninja/pen/drKLzG

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a *column flexbox* and set a height for the `ul` - see demo below:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 150px;
  height: 8em;
}

li {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2</li>
  <li>Item3</li>
  <li>Item4</li>
  <li>Item5</li>
  <li>Item6</li>
  <li>Item7</li>
  <li>Item8</li>
</ul>
```

Or you can use [*CSS columns*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) - see demo below:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  columns: 2; /* added this */
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 150px;
  height: 8em;
}

li {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2</li>
  <li>Item3</li>
  <li>Item4</li>
  <li>Item5</li>
  <li>Item6</li>
  <li>Item7</li>
  <li>Item8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ok cool. yeah, I could have sworn I've done this before, but I can never remember.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add a height / max height and change the direction to column or you can use the column rule:

```
ul {
  list-style:none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 130px;
}
```

or:

```
ul {
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
    columns: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution from above worked best for me:

```
ul {
   -webkit-columns: 2;
   -moz-columns: 2;
   columns: 2;
}
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/55225438/ or else it should have been posted as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the flexbox so that the container will expand width-wise to contain as many as possible items horizontally; in this case, `flex-direction:column` will not work. You may check out https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

Support is skimpy, but it's the only thing that can do what you want (that's why it needed to be introduced): https://caniuse.com/#search=column